# Python - atexit | Calculating global time inside function keyword arguments on process exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, atexit

When I used `def foo(time = calculate_time()): ...`, the parameters (`time`) is 0

> I **suppose** that, keyword argument assignment or atexit is **different process** than main process, so time is irrelevant

```py
from time import time as get_time()

start_time = get_time() # Calculated at the time the application starts

def calculate_time():
    global start_time
    return get_time() - start_time

...

# Set the function which executed on exit
atexit.register(save_to_file)
```

Plese look at **comment lines** in the code which is my KeyLogger script:

> **Sample problematic case:**
>
> - Run python script
> - Immediatly click <kbd>END</kbd> button
> - Floated by zero exception while executing `atexit.register(save_to_file)`
> - Line:  `lines.append(f"Saniye başı tuş basımı (key/s):         {len(pressedKeys) / passing_time}")`

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import atexit
from time import time as get_time
from datetime import datetime

LOG_FILE = "keyLog.txt"
DELIM = "|"
TIME_LIMIT = 20 * 60

start_time = get_time()
pressedKeys = []

def calculate_time():
    global start_time
    return get_time() - start_time

# Why calculate_time() returns 0 
def save_to_file(passing_time = calculate_time()):
    global pressedKeys

    if passing_time is None:
        passing_time = calculate_time() # Why calculate_time() doesn't return 

    with open(LOG_FILE, "a+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        lines = []
        lines.append(f"\n\n\n\n")
        lines.append(f"Tarih (Yıl-Ay-Gün Saat-Dakika-Saniye.): {datetime.now()}")
        lines.append(f"Geçen süre (s):                         {passing_time}")
        lines.append(f"Basılan karakter:                       {len(pressedKeys)}")
        lines.append(f"Saniye başı tuş basımı (key/s):         {len(pressedKeys) / passing_time}")
        lines.append(f"\n")
        lines.append("|".join(pressedKeys))

        file.write("\n".join(lines))

# Set the function which executed on exit
atexit.register(save_to_file)

# Kill process when 'END' is clicked
def on_press(key):
    global pressedKeys

    char = None
    try:
        char = key.char
    except AttributeError:
        char = str(key)

    pressedKeys.append(char)

    time = calculate_time()
    if time > TIME_LIMIT:
        save_to_file(time)


def on_release(key):
    print("")
    if key == keyboard.Key.end:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a keyword argument is calculated upon function definition, not when it is executed.

`time.time` have, at most, the precision of the underlying OS. It is trying to calculate the time it took to assign a list and define a function, this is expectedly rounded down to zero (takes microseconds).

Just change the default value to `None` and the if inside your function will calculate the time difference for when it is called.